# multiple files generation depending on params does not work in async manner

Tags: javascript, node.js

my 1st question here :)

I am relatively new to JS and node.
The part of the code I am building is supposed to generate the files and put data in it depending on the time period that I define.

Code defines amount of files to generate from the interval and then creates+ puts data in it
The problem here is that in Java the loop that would be super easy-> launch the loop, it will do it one by one -> done and in JS because of single thread there are issues so i try using async functions.

```
`switch (myArgs[2]) {
        case 'c':
            if (finalInterval.split("/")[0].split("T")[0] !== finalInterval.split("/")[1].split("T")[0]) {
                filesTOGen = ((Date.parse(finalInterval.split("/")[1].split("T")[0]) - Date.parse(finalInterval.split("/")[0].split("T")[0])) / ((1000 * 3600 * 24))) + 1;
                console.log("about to process the period: ${finalInterval}. Amount of files to generate =${filesTOGen}");
                // Creation
                //for (let z = 0; z < filesTOGen; z++) {\
                var z = 0;
                while (z < filesTOGen) {
                    var pStart = Date.parse(finalInterval.split("/")[0]) + (z * 1000 * 3600 * 24);
                    console.log(pStart);
                    var partialInterval = (new Date(pStart)).toISOString() + "/" + (new Date(pStart)).toISOString().split("T")[0] + "T23:59:59.000Z";
                    (async () => {
                        console.log('before launching');

                        await sqlBuilder(partialInterval, data);


                        console.log('after launching ');
                    })();
                    z++;
                }`
```

When and the code of the sql builder is just creating files with fs.appendFile();
Problem: when i run this code separetely from the bigger application, it successfully generates files and puts data in it, but logs that are produced`console.log('after launching ')` are somehow coming out at the end of the code all together . So if i run the code for 5 days period, there will be 5 console log files at the end of the code execution.
WHen i try to run it with the bigger part of the app, somewhow, it drops all the info in one file only and does not even try to generate other ones.

Any idea where can i look for mistakes?

Comment: For me personally, it is hard to follow your question the way it was written. Maybe it is because of your `async` function? You call your inline defined `async` function directly but you are not waiting for the function itself to return. So, `z++` can be immediaetly executed before the `async` function even starts.

Comment: @enak Thank you . Yeah m a proper way to ask question is smth i need to learn still. What did you mean by the fact that i am not waiting for the function to return ? In my code  the (async () => {
                        console.log('before launching');

                        await sqlBuilder(partialInterval, data);


                        console.log('after launching ');
                    })(); will call the function sqlBuilder which will be like sqlBuilder (){ return sql|Builder1()} and the sqlBuilder1 is also an async function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are a beginner, this is just a wild guess.
You have written down the code and want to execute it synchronously, which simplified means the code should be executed in the same order as the source code lines are written.

The `sqlBuilder` function is `async` and you want it to be executed before moving on. So, you need to write `await sqlBuilder(partialInterval, data);`. You get an error saying that `await` is only allowed in `async` functions.
Therefore you defined an anonymous inner `async` function and call it.
But this is the wrong way!
Now, the anonymous inner function is called but it is called `async`. Therefore you have not gained anything since the code in the `while` loop does not wait for this anonymous `async` function to finish before going on.
You need to make the whole function with the `while` loop `async` or need to to rewrite the code to use the `Promise` of the `sqlBuilder` function.

Comment: Yesm exactly that was the problem. Thank you ! also, any tips on how i can write down a better question so it is more readable next time ?